# Is it possible to remotely access a web server installed on a virtual machine?

Tags: freenas

I am trying to install FreeNAS on VMWare workstation and I wanted to remotely access it. Is it possible? I tried configuring the network interfaces of the freenas but I am unable to access it. Any help would be appreciated.

I have installed freenas with network adapter set to NAT. After installation, it gave me an IP address (192.168.179.137) with which I can access the webGUI. But if I try to change the IP address using configure network option in the freenas, I am unable to access it. My router's default gateway is 192.168.1.1

Also, I tried port forwarding the IP address but it gave me an error that the IP address is not in the same subnet.

Comment: Depends entirely on how you set up the networking in VMware. Show us what you already did and which parts you are having trouble with.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Port Forwarding to a VMware Workstation Virtual Machine](https://superuser.com/questions/571196/port-forwarding-to-a-vmware-workstation-virtual-machine)